# Sending traffic from an interface to another server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables

I have traffic (TCP) coming to a network interface on an Ubuntu server. I would like to send all that incoming traffic to another server, i. e. to its IP address. Nothing else is required (i.e. filtering based on port, etc.) How can I achieve that? Can be either a set of iptables rules, a script, a daemon,...

The servers can be connected via a VPN, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `iptables`.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <incoming_tcp_port> -j DNAT --to-destination <destination_server>:<destination_port>

# Set MASQUERADE so that we can receive responses back.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

You will also need to enable forwarding in your kernel for this to work: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

Source [here](https://my.esecuredata.com/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/49/how-to-redirect-an-incoming-connection-to-a-different-ip-address-on-a-specific-port-using-iptables/).